# aptitude safe-upgrade equivalence with apt-get

Tags: apt, aptitude

Is there an equivalent to doing `aptitude safe-upgrade` using `apt-get`?

Comment: My first thoughts came to dist-upgrade, but I don't think that's actually the same thing as safe-upgrade.

Comment: there is not. aptitude exists to provide stuff not in apt-*

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The `apt-get` command closer to `aptitude safe-upgrade` is `upgrade`, but there is a difference.

`aptitude safe-upgrade` upgrades currently installed packages and can install new packages to resolve new dependencies, but never removes packages.

`apt-get upgrade` upgrades currently installed packages, but never installs or removes packages.

So `apt-get upgrade` is comparable to `aptitude --no-new-installs safe-upgrade`.

Comment: `apt-get upgrade` does not resolve held packages. `aptitude safe-upgrade` does. So far I haven't found any `apt` to replace it

Answer (score 6):

To be a bit more precise on package removal:

man aptitude says:

> -safe-upgrade ... Installed packages will not be removed **unless they are unused** ...

whereas man apt-get says:

> -upgrade ...**under no circumstances** are currently installed packages removed ...

Answer (score 5):

I think that the equivalent would be:

```
apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade
```

And the key is that `--with-new-pkgs` allow installing new packages when used in conjunction with upgrade so it basically do the same thing than `aptitude safe-upgrad`, install upgrades and new packages that are needed by this updates.

Answer (score 3):

Combining PhoenixS's command and Roland Becker's comment about removal of unused packages (and double checking all this in the man pages of `aptitude` and `apt-get`), it would appear that the command using `apt-get` that completely mimics the behvaiour of `aptitude safe-upgrade` is

`apt-get upgrade --with-new-pkgs --autoremove`

This has been tested once on Ubuntu 16.04, and it at least ran, removing some packages and upgrading some other packages, but not installing any new packages (guess it was not necessary in that context)