# Upgrading Ubuntu Jammy

Tags: upgrade

Does the new way of upgrading in Jammy have to be this? `sudo aptitude safe-upgrade` I've noticed after several weeks of old method `sudo apt upgrade` I get left with dozens of packages `kept back` and have to do each one individually. I do not want to add aptitude or force the packages to update. I simply want `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` to work as it has always worked.

Comment: New way? I don't know, but it seems the duplicate I found was 10 years old - so don't know about any new way. Also see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade/).

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/117088/aptitude-safe-upgrade-equivalence-with-apt-get Seems to be just as cumbersome as the other method I posted. Never had this problem till I updated the Distro.

Comment: Probably because [phased updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420969/how-to-force-packages-that-have-been-kept-back-to-be-installed-as-automat/) was introduced then... It's nothing to worry about, packages will be installed eventually - or disable phased updates.

Comment: So if I just wait they will eventually be upgraded?

Comment: Yes - if you run `apt-cache policy <packagename>` you can see how long before it's phased in.

Comment: gonna uninstall aptitude then...Unnecessary!

Answer (score 1):

With Phased updates, the best option is to continue using `apt-get upgrade` and allow the packages that are `kept back` to eventually be phased in. No new method needs to be used, just patience.